# Space with horizontal line in block element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Why is there white space between a horizontal line I'm trying to place between two divs inside a parent block container?

```html
<div className={`absolute w-64 bg-white shadow-custom overflow-hidden 
      z-10 -left-56 mt-1 rounded-[10px] text-center
      [&>div]:w-[90%] [&>div]:inline-flex [&>div]:items-start [&>div]:pl-4 [&>div]:flex-col
      [&>div]:justify-center
      [&>div:not(:last-child)]:bg-[#fef2ed] [&>div:hover]:cursor-pointer [&>div]:rounded-lg
      ${userDropdown ? " h-44" : "h-0"} duration-200`}>
        <section className="inline-flex p-4">
          <button title="profile-pic" className="rounded-full bg-black h-12 w-12 mr-2">
              hola
          </button>
          <span className="text-left">
            <p className=" text-2xl leading-none">Nombre</p>
            <p className="flex leading-1">nombre@gmail.com</p>
          </span>
        </section>
        <div className="h-8">
          Modificar datos
        </div>
        {/* <div className="!h-0 justify-center !pl-0">
          <span className="border border-t-0 w-full"/>
        </div> */}
        <div className="h-1 border border-t-0 w-full"></div>
        <div className="h-8 bg-[#f7b4bb]">
          Log out
        </div>
      </div>
```

I'm using tailwind and this is what is showing:

[image]

As you can see there's a space between the first div and the log out div. One way I fixed is with flex, but that gives problem to the opening transition so I want this to be block so that the inside content doesn't arrange when the height is 0.

Comment: Because you have an empty div there `<div className="h-1 border border-t-0 w-full"></div>`

Comment: @Konrad yeah, but i want that div to act like a divider. Is that possible?